# R filterings rows that contain a combination of words

Tags: r, text, dplyr, filtering

I am working with text data, and looking for a solution to a filtering problem.

I have managed to find a solution which filters for rows that contain 'Word 1' **OR** 'Word 2'

Here's the reproducible code

```
df=data.frame(UID=c(1,2,3,4,5),Text=c("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
                                 "long live the king",
                                 "I love my dog a lot",
                                 "Tomorrow will be a rainy day",
                                 "Tomorrow will be a sunny day"))


#Filter for rows that contain "brown" OR "dog"
filtered_results_1=dplyr::filter(df, grepl('brown|dog', Text))
```

However when I filter for rows that contain both 'Word 1' **AND** 'Word 2', it doesn't work.

```
#Filter for rows that contain "brown" AND "dog"
filtered_results_2=dplyr::filter(df, grepl('brown & dog', Text))
```

Cannot figure out the right syntax for this one, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a double `grepl`

```
dplyr::filter(df, grepl('\\bbrown\\b', Text) & grepl('\\bdog\\b', Text))
```

---

or use a condition where we check the word 'brown' followed by the word 'dog' (note the word boundary (`\\b`) to make sure that it won't match anything else) or 'dog' followed by 'brown'

```
dplyr::filter(df, grepl("\\bbrown\\b.*\\bdog\\b|\\bdog\\b.*\\bbrown\\b", Text))
#   UID                                         Text
#1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

NOTE: It checks the word boundary, the words 'brown', 'dog', presence of both of them in the string

---

It can also be done with `base R`

```
subset(df, grepl("\\bbrown\\b.*\\bdog\\b|\\bdog\\b.*\\bbrown\\b", Text))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `stringr::str_count` :

```
dplyr::mutate(df, test = stringr::str_count(Text,'brown|dog'))
#   UID                                         Text test
# 1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog    2
# 2   2                           long live the king    0
# 3   3                          I love my dog a lot    1
# 4   4                 Tomorrow will be a rainy day    0
# 5   5                 Tomorrow will be a sunny day    0

dplyr::filter(df, stringr::str_count(Text,'brown|dog') == 2)
#   UID                                         Text
# 1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

It will count `dog` or `brown` as many times as they occur though

The following is more general, less elegant than some, but you can conveniently put the searched words in a vector :

```
dplyr::filter(df, purrr::map_int(strsplit(as.character(Text),'[[:punct:] ]'),
               ~sum(unique(.) %in% c("brown","dog"))) == 2)

#   UID                                         Text
# 1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Comment: Just wondering , if they have two dog in one string  , will this count as 2 ?

Comment: ah, yes it will indeed, the solution isn't general, good catch

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
filtered_results_2=dplyr::filter(df, grepl('brown.*dog|dog.*brown', Text))
filtered_results_2
  UID                                         Text
1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where Text like '%dog%' AND Text like '%brown%'")
```

Output:

```
    UID                                         Text
     1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous answers but using `base`

```
df[grepl("(?=.*dog)(?=.*brown)", df$Text, perl = TRUE),]
  UID                                         Text
1   1 the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```